# Angular Gridster 2, nested Grids

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, angular-gridster2

I am facing an issue with angular gridster 2, I want to have nested gridster,
Here is the configs I am using

```
zItemsNesteing: IGridsterConfig = {
    gridsterConfig: this.gridsterOptions,
    gridsterItems: [
      {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        rows: 2,
        cols: 2,
        zItems: {
          gridsterConfig: this.gridsterOptions,
          gridsterItems: [
            { x: 0, y: 0, rows: 2, cols: 2},
            { x: 2, y: 0, rows: 1, cols: 1 },
          ],
        },
      },
      { x: 0, y: 0, rows: 2, cols: 2 },
    ],
  };`enter code here`
```

Here is my component

```
<div class="gridster-container">
    <app-grid
      [options]="zItemsNesteing.gridsterConfig"
      [dashboard]="zItemsNesteing.gridsterItems"
    ></app-grid>
  </div>
```

and here I am trying nesting

```
<gridster [options]="options">
  <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
    Hello
    <div class="gridster-container" *ngIf="item.zItems">
      <app-grid
        [options]="item.zItems.gridsterConfig"
        [dashboard]="item.zItems.gridsterItems"
      ></app-grid>
    </div>
  </gridster-item>
</gridster>
```

This is my output, nested gridster seems not working.

[image]

**If you see in nested gridster we have two items but it is comming one after another instead of on the same row and the specified colummn.**